# Troubles with python dateparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, dateparser

I am using dateparser and i have got a case, when in the string with date there are other words and I have detected that it doesn't return expected result in this case.

```
from dateparser import parse

print(parse('April 19, 2006')) # returns 2006-04-19 00:00:00
print(parse('April 19, 2006 test test')) # returns None
```

How it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documentation](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#search-for-dates-in-longer-chunks-of-text) has already warned

> Support for searching dates is really limited and needs a lot of improvement, we look forward to community’s contribution to get better on that part

it's better not to use it that way. but there's a function for this case. try

```py
from dateparser.search import search_dates
print(search_dates('April 19, 2006 test test'))
```

output:

```
[('April 19, 2006', datetime.datetime(2006, 4, 19, 0, 0))]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `parse('April 19, 2006')` returns a datetime object representing the date and time April 19, 2006 at 00:00:00. This is because the input string 'April 19, 2006' contains a well-formatted date and does not contain any extraneous information that could confuse the parsing algorithm.

However, when you pass the string `April 19, 2006 test test` to the parse function, it returns `None` because the string contains additional text that is not part of a valid date format.

If you want to parse a string that includes additional text, you can use the `dateutil` module instead:

```
from dateutil import parser

print(parser.parse('April 19, 2006')) # returns 2006-04-19 00:00:00
print(parser.parse('April 19, 2006 test test')) # returns 2006-04-19 00:00:00
```